# Django -JSON not serializable type-error while integrating paypal

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, django, paypal

Whenever I try to pay using paypal on my website it throws an error

```
Internal Server Error: /paypal/create/18/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ukfle\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\ukfle\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\ukfle\Documents\pro\a\views.py", line 69, in create
    response = client.execute(create_order)
  File "C:\Users\ukfle\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\paypalhttp\http_client.py", line 52, in execute
    data = self.encoder.serialize_request(reqCpy)
  File "C:\Users\ukfle\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\paypalhttp\encoder.py", line 15, in serialize_request
    return enc.encode(httprequest)
  File "C:\Users\ukfle\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\paypalhttp\serializers\json_serializer.py", line 7, in encode
    return json.dumps(request.body)
  File "C:\Users\ukfle\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\json\__init__.py", line 231, in dumps
    return _default_encoder.encode(obj)
  File "C:\Users\ukfle\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\json\encoder.py", line 199, in encode
    chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
  File "C:\Users\ukfle\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\json\encoder.py", line 257, in iterencode
    return _iterencode(o, 0)
  File "C:\Users\ukfle\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\json\encoder.py", line 179, in default
    raise TypeError(f'Object of type {o.__class__.__name__} '
TypeError: Object of type Decimal is not JSON serializable
```

here are my views:

```
def pay(request, pk):
    client_id = settings.PAYPAL_CLIENT_ID
    course = get_object_or_404(t_data,pk=pk)
    context={'course':course, 'client_id':client_id }
    return render(request, 'pay.html',context)
def create(request,id):
    if request.method =="POST":
        environment = SandboxEnvironment(client_id=settings.PAYPAL_CLIENT_ID, client_secret=settings.PAYPAL_SECRET_ID)
        client = PayPalHttpClient(environment)
        course = t_data.objects.get(pk=id)
        create_order = OrdersCreateRequest()
        create_order.request_body (
            {
                "intent": "CAPTURE",
                "purchase_units": [
                    {
                        "amount": {
                            "currency_code": "USD",
                            "value": course.file_price,
                            "breakdown": {
                                "item_total": {
                                    "currency_code": "USD",
                                    "value": course.file_price
                                }
                                },
                            },                               
                        
                        
                    }
                ]
            }
        )

        response = client.execute(create_order)
        data = response.result.__dict__['_dict']
        return JsonResponse(data)
    else:
        return JsonResponse({'details': "invalide request"})
        

def capture(request,order_id,id):
    if request.method =="POST":
        capture_order = OrdersCaptureRequest(order_id)
        environment = SandboxEnvironment(client_id=settings.PAYPAL_CLIENT_ID, client_secret=settings.PAYPAL_SECRET_ID)
        client = PayPalHttpClient(environment)
        
        response = client.execute(capture_order)
        data = response.result.__dict__['_dict']
        return JsonResponse(data)
    else:
        return JsonResponse({'details': "invalide request"})

def getClientId(request):
    if request.method == "GET":        
        return JsonResponse({'client_id':  settings.PAYPAL_CLIENT_ID})
```

here is my pay.html file

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load static %}

{% block content %}
  <div class="card w-25 shadow" >      
        <div class="card-body">
            <div class="card-title">
                <h2>{{course.file_name}}</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="card-text">
                <p class="text-muted">{{course.file_desc}}</p><br>
                <div class="h4">Price: <strong>{{course.file_price}}</strong></div>
            </div>

        </div>
        <div class="card-footer bg-white"> 
            <input id="course-id"  value={{course.id}} hidden/>         
            <div id="paypal-button-container"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endblock %}

{% block extrascript %}
    <script src="https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id={{client_id}}&disable-funding=credit,card" > </script> 
    <script src="{% static  'js/main.js' %}" ></script>
{% endblock %}
```

and here is my main.js file

```
    function getCookie(name) {
    let cookieValue = null;
    if (document.cookie && document.cookie !== '') {
        const cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
        for (let i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
            const cookie = cookies[i].trim();
            // Does this cookie string begin with the name we want?
            if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) === (name + '=')) {
                cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return cookieValue;
}

const csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken');
const course_id = document.getElementById('course-id').value
        paypal.Buttons({

            // Call your server to set up the transaction
            createOrder: function(data, actions) {
                return fetch('/paypal/create/'+course_id+'/', {
                    method: 'post',
                    headers: {"X-CSRFToken": csrftoken}
                }).then(function(res) {
                    return res.json();
                }).then(function(orderData) {
                    console.log(orderData)
                    return orderData.id;
                });
            },

            // Call your server to finalize the transaction
            onApprove: function(data, actions) {
                return fetch('/paypal/' + data.orderID + '/capture/'+course_id+'/', {
                    method: 'post',
                    headers: {"X-CSRFToken": csrftoken}
                }).then(function(res) {
                    return res.json();
                }).then(function(orderData) {
                    // Three cases to handle:
                    //   (1) Recoverable INSTRUMENT_DECLINED -> call actions.restart()
                    //   (2) Other non-recoverable errors -> Show a failure message
                    //   (3) Successful transaction -> Show a success / thank you message

                    // Your server defines the structure of 'orderData', which may differ
                    var errorDetail = Array.isArray(orderData.details) && orderData.details[0];

                    if (errorDetail && errorDetail.issue === 'INSTRUMENT_DECLINED') {
                        // Recoverable state, see: "Handle Funding Failures"
                        // https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/integration-features/funding-failure/
                        return actions.restart();
                    }

                    if (errorDetail) {
                        var msg = 'Sorry, your transaction could not be processed.';
                        if (errorDetail.description) msg += '\n\n' + errorDetail.description;
                        if (orderData.debug_id) msg += ' (' + orderData.debug_id + ')';
                        // Show a failure message
                        return alert(msg);
                    }

                    // Show a success message to the buyer
                    alert('Transaction completed by ' + orderData.payer.name.given_name);
                });
            }


        }).render('#paypal-button-container');
```

The error occurs when i try to open paypal shipping window by clicking the paypal button(normal paypal button that we use for payment) And the error shows up on terminal only. How to fix this?
Please

Thank you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> TypeError: Object of type Decimal is not JSON serializable

The error is pretty clear. Try casting the Decimal to a String first.

Comment: It says error in Create


Internal Server Error: /paypal/create/18/

can you show me where I have to cast the decimal to string

Comment: Did you review the quoted traceback? `TypeError: Object of type Decimal is not JSON serializable`

Comment: sir I am a quite beginner ,can you show me where I have to cast the decimal to string

Comment: Probably when you reference `course.file_price`